# Multivariate central limit theorem with unknown variance

Tags: multivariate-analysis, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be samples from a distribution on $\mathbb{R}^d$ that has a finite second moment.

If $d=1$, $\bar{X}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $S_n=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X}_n)^2$ then 
$$\sqrt{n}\frac{\bar{X}_n-\mu}{S_n}\rightarrow_n \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$ in distribution.
I know that the same statement holds for $d>1$ if we additionally assume that we are given the covariance matrix $\Sigma$, that is $$\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)\rightarrow_n \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma).$$
However, I can't find a reference for the multivariate CLT with a covariance matrix estimator instead of $\Sigma$ as in the one-dimensional case $d=1$ (though I am pretty sure it must exists).

Edit: To clarify, my question is what is the multivariate version of $\sqrt{n}\frac{\bar{X}_n-\mu}{S_n}\rightarrow_n \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, i.e. can I replace $S_n$ with an appropiate covariance estimator if $d>1$?

Comment: [The Wikipedia article on the CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Multidimensional_CLT) points out how the univariate CLT extends immediately to the multivariate one.

Comment: Thanks - but I only see the case with known variance $\Sigma$ discussed there. I am asking if $\Sigma$ can be replaced with a covariance estimator when $d>1$.

Comment: On the contrary--that case does not assume $\Sigma$ is known.  The random variables could care less whether you or anyone else knows their properties: the sequence of means will *still* be subject to the CLT!

Comment: Yes, it will converge to $\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ but I if I use it as test statistic (Wald test, etc) I need to normalize by an estimator for the covariance matrix as in the case $d=1$ that I spelled out in my question.

Comment: Your question, as currently written, is about *asymptotic* behavior, which is completely different than issues of normalization in a particular *finite* sample.  What are you actually trying to ask here?

Comment: My question is what's the multivariate version of $\sqrt{n}\frac{\bar{X}_n-\mu}{S_n}\rightarrow_n \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, i.e. can I replace $S_n$ with a covariance estimator if $d>1$